# Why can't I call a Polymer function on an element?

Tags: javascript, polymer

This is really bugging me, can't seem to get this to work and I figure it's got to be some small little thing I'm overlooking. I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functiontest-index.html:16 (anonymous function)`

Here's code to reproduce, first the element:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="test-element" >
    <template>
        <div>YOOOOO</div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            loaderup: function(event, detail, sender) {
                alert("WAT?")
            }
        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

And here's the page that's trying to load it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>MyApp</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="test-element.html">
</head>

<body unresolved>

<test-element id="test-el"></test-element>

<script>
    var x = document.querySelector("#test-el");
    console.log(x);
    x.loaderup();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it gives the error I posted about on `x.loaderup()`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the [*polymer-ready* event](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#polymer-ready), because the Polymer element upgrade is performed asynchronously:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function() {
    var x = document.querySelector("#test-el");
    console.log(x);
    x.loaderup();
  });
</script>
```